# For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $v=\{1,2,...,n\}$, how many graphs $G=(V,E)$ are there such that the even numbered vertexes are not connected??

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Given an even $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $v=\{1,2,...,n\}$, how many graphs $G=(V,E)$ are there such that the even numbered vertexes are not connected?

I started to say that there are $\binom{n/2}{2}$ even vertex-pairs, then for each pair there are $2$ possibilities we either put an edge or not , so we have $2^{\binom{n/2}{2}}$.
Then we know the total number of graphs is $2^n$ , so my answer was $2^n\cdot 2^{\binom{n/2}{2}}$.
Is this a right approach or did I miss something?

Comment: I'm skeptical of "the total number of graphs is $2^n$" for starters. When you say "the even numbered vertexes are not connected", what do you mean exactly? That no two even vertices have an edge between them? That the even vertices don't all lie in the same connected component of the graph? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is just $2^\binom{n/2}{2}$, assuming that $V = v$.

But when you include the factor $2^n$, I assume your intent is to consider that each member of $v$ may or may not be a vertex.  It is incorrect to multiply by $2^n$ in this case, however.  You only have the option to omit a vertex when it is isolated:  i.e., not incident with any edge.  You have at least $n/2$ of these, of course.

To answer your question, let $k$ of the $n/2$ odd vertices be present.  There are $\binom{n/2}{k}$ ways to choose these vertices, and $2^\binom{k}{2}$ (labeled) graphs on those vertices.  There are also $2^{n/2}$ choices for including each even vertex or not.  Therefore the count you seek is $$
2^{n/2} \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n/2}{k} 2^\binom{k}{2}.
$$
If we omit the condition that even-numbered vertices are isolated the formula is modified to
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^\binom{k}{2},
$$
which is sequence [A006896](https://oeis.org/A006896) in the OEIS.